# Cellular Automata rule function in mathematica / notebook source, Patterns, Alternatives

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I found this from a Cellular Automata Mathematica file, what is pattern and alternatives?

In this block of code, what does Pattern mean:

```
CellularAutomaton[{ { 0, Blank[], 3} -> 0, 
                        { Blank[], 2, 3} -> 3, 
                        { 1, 1, 3 }      -> 4, 
                        { Blank[], 1, 4} -> 4, 
                        { Alternatives[1, 2] << 1 or 2 >>, 3, Blank[]} -> 5, 
                        { Pattern[$CellContext`p, Alternatives[0, 1]], 4, Blank[]} -> 7 - $CellContext`p, 
                        { 7, 2, 6} -> 3, 
                        { 7, Blank[], Blank[]} -> 7,  
                        { Blank[], 7, Pattern[$CellContext`p, Alternatives[1, 2]]} -> $CellContext`p, 
                        { Blank[], Pattern[$CellContext`p, Alternatives[5, 6]], Blank[]} -> 7 - $CellContext`p, 
                        { Alternatives[5, 6], Pattern[$CellContext`p, Alternatives[1, 2]], Blank[]} -> 7 - $CellContext`p, 
                        { Alternatives[5, 6], 0, 0} -> 1, 
                        { Blank[], Pattern[$CellContext`p, Alternatives[1, 2]], Blank[]} -> $CellContext`p, 
                        { Blank[],  Blank[], Blank[]} -> 0}, {
```

Answer (score 2):

You are defining a Cellular Automaton explicitly.

Each row defines an evolution rule.

You may find the relevant information [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellularAutomaton.html).

A few hints for reading your code:

```
Blank[] is the blank pattern "_" that matches any expression  

Pattern[] is Mathematica construct for pattern matching  

Alternatives[a,b,c] is the full form for a | b| c ... any of "a, b or c"  

Pattern[p, Alternatives[a, b]] names as p the matched expr (a or b)
```

**Edit**

So, as an example, the following Automatons are made equivalent:

```
CellularAutomaton[{
   {1, 0} -> 1,
   {1, 1} -> 0,
   {0, 1} -> 1,
   {0, 0} -> 1},
  {0, 1, 0}, 10]  

CellularAutomaton[{
   {1, Pattern[t, Alternatives[1, 0]]} -> Abs[1 - t],
   {0, 1} -> 1,
   {0, 0} -> 1
   }, {0, 1, 0}, 10]
```

Note: The example is just for you to ease the understanding of the code you posted. There are better ways to define this Automaton.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I would throw that question out there and someone did respond.

Comment: I still don't understand the role of the Pattern match.  What would be the difference between the alternatives and Pattern match with alternatives.

Comment: For example, here:   { Pattern[$CellContext`p, Alternatives[0, 1]], 4, Blank[]} -> 7 - $CellContext`p, ... name the pattern P, (0 or 1) but what does "7 - $CellContext`p" mean?  Also, why is pattern used here and not just Alternatives.

Comment: @Berlin Is anything missing in my answer?